# How come when I change the order of these they work?

Tags: css, colors, font-size

I'm totally new to coding and just trying to find my feet, I have been given a challenge to do on the course I am taking which I have solved but my solution was to write the same 2 lines of code but in a different order.

Whilst it's great that this worked I'm confused at to why!

Can anyone help me?

This one works

em {
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white
}

This way doesn't work it completely ignores my request for color and font size and leaves it with the rules I set in an earlier part of the code.

em {
        color:white
    font-size: 20px;
}

I would expect both ways to work as my understanding was CSS reads from top to bottom and this is the bottom of the code so there's nothing which can negate this rule.

Comment: You need a semicolon after the word "white" in the second example. Only the last one is not mandatory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a semi-colon on the colour:

```css
p {
  color: red;
}

em {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
 }

em {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<p> Test <em>Word</em></p>
```

This should work for you, you're right that the styling should cascade down.

Comment: You absolute legend, I knew it would be something silly I was overlooking.

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you mark as the accepted answer please for any users who come to this with similar issues?